# Block sites at specific times

Tags: macos, safari, websites

When at college I sometimes find myself looking at website such as [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) and [Mac Rumours](http://www.macrumors.com/). Is there a way how to block sites like this on Yosemite every 1.5hr with 30min break?

What I mean is, is there an application to block specific websites at time such as 9:00-10:30 then again 11:00-12:30 etc?

This would help me to do more work at college and not get distracted. I would like an application that blocks the sites for ALL applications, however a Safari extension will work too (I only use Safari so Chrome extensions will be useless). I know editing the hosts file could work however I want it to change at certain times (I may try and make a script if no applications work :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WasteNoTime](http://www.bumblebeesystems.com/wastenotime/) is a Safari browser extension which should have the requested features according to the website:

> **WasteNoTime** is a browser extension which is designed to help you manage your time spent on the Internet more efficiently.
>
> **Time Tracker** feature gives you reports on what web sites you spent most of your time.
> **Instant Lockdown** feature allows you to focus on your work for a period of time with limited Internet access.
> **Time Quota** feature automatically block selected web sites when you have spent a preset amount of time on them each day.

Comment: Only issue is I can disable the extension. :)

Answer (score 0):

[SelfControl](https://selfcontrolapp.com/) is an app that blocks your blacklisted websites until its timer runs out. It's supposed to be so impenetrable that even deleting the app and rebooting your computer won't lift the block, though, so make sure you don't blacklist anything that you may possibly need before time's up.

Comment: Can that block sites automatically when a time has been set? For example can it automatically turn on at 9:00 and stop at 10:30 and then restart at 11:00 until 12:30 etc? Doesn't look like it does.

Comment: No, it has to be manually switched on every time.

Comment: I want it to start automatically. What if I 'forget' to turn it on :) . Also is there a way to use wildcards ('`*`'). This is because I don't want to enter all stack exchange sites manual so I would like to do '*.stackexchange.com'. Or would blocking 'stackexchange.com' block all SE sites?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's been a while since I've used it. I just saw your request for a website blacklist and remembered this app.

Comment: Hey, its code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/SelfControlApp/selfcontrol/). You could mess with the code and see if you can find a way to automate it.

Comment: Yea. I may do since I can program. Fun challenge ahead! Just don't want it to distract me from my work though! Lol. Would you like me to upload it afterwards so you can check it out?